# Go Gin converting json response to base64

Tags: json, go, go-gin, encoding-json-go

I am trying to send db query data as json response . Here is my controller :

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/json-iterator/go"
    "log"
)

func GetNewsPapers()  []byte{
    db := GetDB()

    var json = jsoniter.ConfigCompatibleWithStandardLibrary

    rows, err := db.Queryx(`SELECT title, language, ranking, slug, search_term, logo_url FROM public.news_newspaper`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()
    tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)

    for rows.Next() {
        entry := make(map[string]interface{})
        err := rows.MapScan(entry)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        tableData = append(tableData, entry)
    }

    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(tableData)

    fmt.Println(string(jsonData))  // printing expected json
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return jsonData
}
```

and

```
func (n *NewsPaperController) GetList(c *gin.Context) {
    value := database.GetNewsPapers()
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, value)
}
```

Problem is I am getting base64 string as response not the json object I am expecting. If I convert `value` to string like below, I get human readable values .

```
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, string(value))
```

But whole response encoded in string like this:

```
"[{\"language\":\"en\",\"logo_url\":\"..\",\"ranking\":2,\"search_term\":\"..\",\"slug\":\"..\",\"title\":\"....\"}]
```

How do I get json response like below:

```
 [{"language":"en","logo_url":"..","ranking":2,"search_term":"..","slug":"..","title":".."} ]
```

Comment: You should decide on only one: am I gonna marshal this myself using `json.Marshal`? Or am I gonna leave the marshaling to gin and use `c.JSON`? But you should not do both, marshaling already marshaled json bytes makes no sense.

Comment: @mkopriva which one is more performant ?

Comment: They are the same, gin uses json.Marshal under the hood. But since you're using gin you should use gin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> func (c *Context) JSON(code int, obj interface{})
>
> JSON serializes the
> given struct as JSON into the response body. It also sets the
> Content-Type as "application/json".

`c.JSON()` serialize as JSON you don't need to unmarshal before use it. Use `tableData` in `c.JSON()`

```
func GetNewsPapers()  []map[string]interface{}{
    // your existing code
    return tableData
}

func (n *NewsPaperController) GetList(c *gin.Context) {
    value := database.GetNewsPapers()
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, value)
}
```

And using `%#v` you can see Go-syntax representation of the value where you will found the escape character also

```
fmt.Printf("%#v", string(jsonData))
```